# Android Development via Java Eclipse: I am Exporting But It Is Not Exporting As .apk file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, export, apk

I am fairly new to Java android development and have exported my apps in the past as .apk files however today, it is exporting it as an unknown file to me.  I really need the .apk 
file.  Can anyone help?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click your project, click Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package.

Comment: I have done this step however for some reason, it is ending up exporting as a file that is not .apk

Comment: When you choose the name/destination you must specify the .apk extension.

Comment: Any answer is good! haha. I just don't like when people ask a question, get the answer, and are never to be seen again until they have another question!

Answer (score 0):

usually you can just add `.apk` to the file name and i will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If your project builds than you just have to go into the bin folder of your project (via Explorer) and grap the .apk. (Of course this is not officially signed but good for testing)